# Can I deduct DC Unemployment Insurance on D-20?

Tags: united-states, taxes, district-of-columbia

Where would,if possible, a D.C.-based for-profit corporation (S-Corp at federal level) be able to deduct Unemployment Insurance on the D-20 for?

I've looked at the 2018 D-20 District of Columbia Corporate Franchise Tax Forms and Instructions and there's no reference to the unemployment insurance.

Comment: The Federal Government allows the deduction of UI as a business expense. As such I would deduct it either as a misc expense, or as a wage.

Comment: @JakeFreeman I see the D-20 has a Deductions section. Do you mean the Deductions section under "24 Other Deductions" for misc expense or am I missing something since I don't see it?
If DC OTR didn't allow it, would this be considered a double-tax?

Comment: Some additional information is provided in UI Employer Handbook, but it doesn't address this specific topic of how the UI can be deducted as a business expense, but does note that the Federal Unemployment Tax Act UI may be reduced by paying DC UI under section "Federal Unemployment Taxes " https://essp.does.dc.gov/UI%20Employer%20Handbook.pdf